# Why does this code create the correct pattern?

Tags: c, loops

I've recently started to learn the C programming language and therefore started tackling problems on Hackerrank. One of the problems is as follows:

> In this problem, you need to print the pattern of the following form containing the numbers from 1 to `n`.
>
> ```
> 4 4 4 4 4 4 4  
> 4 3 3 3 3 3 4   
> 4 3 2 2 2 3 4   
> 4 3 2 1 2 3 4   
> 4 3 2 2 2 3 4   
> 4 3 3 3 3 3 4   
> 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
> ```

[I saw a programmer on YouTube. He wrote a very short program to solve it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zk0dmzsDsDU&list=PLtfRFndo6b7LFJ3WARQep4cAlsmqgqxw0&index=10&t=0s):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max(x,y) ((x)>(y)?x:y)
int main() 
{

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int len = n*2 - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
            printf("%d ",max( abs(n -i-1) + 1, abs(n-j-1) +1 ));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I already listed all the indexing of the `2n-1 x 2n-1` matrix and tried to observe the relationship. But I can't formulate the relation of `max( abs(n -i-1) + 1, abs(n-j-1) +1 )`.

I just don't get the idea of `max( abs(n -i-1) + 1, abs(n-j-1) +1 )`, why does this line of code get the correct the value of each element in the matrix?

Comment: take a sheet of paper, pen or pencil, and execute the code manually. You will understand it. When you learn programming try to analyse programs this way. It will give you much more than thousands of internet posts

Comment: I dry run the code manually, and does the max( abs(n -i-1) + 1, abs(n-j-1) +1 ) really gives out the correct element of each matrix. But just don't know how to formulate this max( abs(n -i-1) + 1, abs(n-j-1) +1 ) from the very beginning.

Comment: Guys, I understood finally.